# The value of expression of type 'void' can't be used in then()

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

How to fix this kind of errors when using `then`?

```
void handleSubmitWrapper() {
  final future = handleSubmit();
  future.then(context.loaderOverlay.hide()); // error
}

Future<void> handleSubmit() async {
  ...
}
```

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. Try
> checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a
> function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type
> parameters and variables which might also be void.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide an anonymous function in your case, which has type FutureOr Function(void).

```
 future.then((void _) => context.loaderOverlay.hide());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this `dart:async`, lets have a look at what you could do when you don't use that `then` anachronism:

```
Future<void> handleSubmitWrapper() async {
  await handleSubmit();

  if (!context.mounted) return;

  context.loaderOverlay.hide();
}
```

Bonus: you are now able to `await` this method. Or continue it with a `then` if you must. Or not. Your choice.

Comment: this code produces a warning `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps`, so using `then` is a way to level it, isn't it?

Comment: @rozerro You are correct, I fxed that.